# Xamarin Forms - binding to a ControlTemplate

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am having trouble getting bindings defined in a ControlTemplate to work against my model.

Notice in the below ControlTemplate, I am using a TemplateBinding to bind to a property called Count (olive label).  I am using Parent.Count as [prescribed by this article](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/templates/control-templates/template-binding/), but neither values of **Parent.Count** nor **Count** are working.

[image]

The following page uses the ControlTemplate.  Just to prove my ViewModel works I have a gray Label bound to the Count property as well.

[image]

Notice the resulting screen.  The gray label is showing the Count property.  The olive label from the ControlTemplate is not showing anything.

[image]

How can I make the Label in the ControlTemplate show the Count property from the ViewModel?

**VIEW MODEL**

```
namespace SimpleApp
{
    public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            _count = 10;
            Uptick = new Command(() => { Count++; });
        }

        private int _count;
        public int Count
        {
            get { return _count; }
            set
            {
                _count = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Count");
            }
        }

        public ICommand Uptick { get; private set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SimpleApp"
             x:Class="SimpleApp.MainPage"
             ControlTemplate="{StaticResource ParentPage}">
    <StackLayout>
        <Button Command="{Binding Uptick}" Text="Increment Count" />
        <Label Text="{Binding Count}" BackgroundColor="Gray" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**CODE BEHIND**

Notice the BindingContext is set to MainViewModel here.  I need to use my own ViewModel and not the code behind.

```
namespace SimpleApp
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            BindingContext = new MainViewModel();

            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

**CONTROL TEMPLATE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="SimpleApp.App">
    <Application.Resources>

        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="ParentPage">

                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{TemplateBinding Parent.Count}" BackgroundColor="Olive" />
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </StackLayout>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: Should it be <Label Text="{TemplateBinding Count}" BackgroundColor="Olive" />   ?

Comment: I tried that already, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Also check for update to the NuGets packages and Xamarin Itself? I reinstalled my PC, don´t have Xamarin here now. I would like to test here.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

On your ControlTemplate please use the following code:

```
<Label Text="{TemplateBinding BindingContext.Count}" BackgroundColor="Olive" />
```

It seems that BindingContext is not being automatically applied to your ContentPage child, maybe it could be a bug in Xamarin.